# UITableViewCell Expand UIWebview Height Dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have an UITableView which includes a list of UITableViewCells. And I set the heights of UITableViewCells.

Comment: what is your question man?? can you make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableViewDelegate should implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
return [indexPath row] * 20;// or whatever you need to set height
}
```

or

**If all the cells are the same, set the rowHeight property on UITableView to the size of your cell. If they're all different based on content, you're going to have to implement -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and calculate the height for each row based on your data source.**